# Submit in for loop only firing once

Tags: jquery, loops, submit

Im trying to get get .submit() to run with each pass of a for loop but it only ever runs once. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
$("#fancyConfirm_ok").click(function () {
    proceedAfterRestrictionCheckGuest();
    for (var rowNum = 0; rowNum < prodCode.length; ++rowNum) {
        var rProd = prodCode[rowNum];
        console.log(prodCode[rowNum]);
        var rPos = prodCarPos[rowNum];
        console.log(prodCarPos[rowNum]);
        $("#entryNumber").prop('value', rPos);
        $("#quantity").prop('value', 0);
        $('#updateRestrictionForm').submit();
    }
    $.fancybox.close();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: When you submit a form, the page is reloaded, so your script stops.

Comment: Or you are using `ajax` to submit form

Comment: As @barmar said, form submission reloads the page. What is it you are wanting to do? You could `e.preventDefault()` the submission event

Comment: @JoshStevenson He's calling `.submit()` explicitly in the function, so the submission event is irrelevant.

Comment: @barmar unless he has changed the method for that form elsewhere in the code? `$('#updateRestrictionForm').submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });`?

Comment: Hi Barmar I suspected my script was stopping on the reload. Is there a way to run the submit without it reloading the page or another way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar points out, the default submit action on the form will be fired when do you call `$('#updateRestrictionForm').submit();`, so the form will be submitted which makes the page reload and consequently stop your script.

As [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) docs points out, "you can cancel the submit action by calling .preventDefault() on the event object or by returning false from our handler". All you need to do is to catch the submit event and cancel its propagation across the DOM (bubbling).

Something like:

```
$( "#updateRestrictionForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Please note that the underline concepts of my answer are not jQuery specific. I'm only using jQuery docs and code since it seems to be the easier way to do it knowing that you are using it in your code.

Comment: Hi, have tried the prevent default, and it ran through the array ok but didn't submit any of the info. I've re-thought the process and have sent the array to the server and have now written some java to process the array.